# "Block all cookies" in Safari (desktop) seems to block none

Tags: safari

**Safari 12.1.1 - OSX 10.14.5**

I want to block all cookies and local storage in Safari and so set that as an option. Yet when I check what data has been stored, there is always an extensive list of cached data (and no way to see any details about that data).

Am I misunderstanding what "block all cookies" is supposed to do?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is it new data? cookies aren't generally readable either. They'd be in ~/Library folder I guess.

Comment: fyi: You will not be able to much work on today's web when blocking all cookies.

Comment: "Cache" is not cookies.  Cookies is listed as "cookies", and HTML LocalStorage is listed as "local storage", etc.

Comment: blocking all the cookies won't stop the browser from storing "data". I think you have to study more about Cookies. "Cache" is not actually "Cookie".